# Using CSS to keep two images together on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am pretty new to HTML and CSS.

Right now I have a 4 column layout that has 4 images all next to each other on a desktop view and when in mobile, all the icons are stacked on top of one another. Here is an image to explain.

[DESKTOP VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0i2r.png)

I am not allowed to post more than one link, so I will use x's to explain.

This is desktop view using x's:
X X X X

This is the current mobile view using x's" 
X 
X 
X 
X 
(all the images / icons are stacked on one another)

This is what I am trying to achieve using CSS:
X X
X X
(images are grouped together on one line)

I saw a post using float left and float right attributes targeted for small screen sizes. Not sure if that would work. I would love some help.

```css
/* 1 column: 320px */
.autowide {
  margin: 0 auto;
 width: 94%;
}


/* 2 columns: 330px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 330px) {
  .hot-icon-group {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2.564102564102564%;
  width: 48.717948717948715%;
 }
 .hot-icon-group:nth-child(2n+0) {
  margin-right: 0;
 }
}

/* 3 columns: 768px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .autowide .hot-icon-group {
  width: 31.623931623931625%;
 }
 .autowide .hot-icon-group:nth-child(2n+0) {
  margin-right: 2.564102564102564%;
 }
 .autowide .hot-icon-group:nth-child(3n+0) {
  margin-right: 0;
 }
}

/* 4 columns: 992px and up */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .autowide .hot-icon-group {
  width: 23.076923076923077%;
 }
 .autowide .hot-icon-group:nth-child(3n+0) {
  margin-right: 2.564102564102564%;
 }
 .autowide .hot-icon-group:nth-child(4n+0) {
  margin-right: 0;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="autowide">
    <img src="https://beaverbuilder.appletreeprinting.ca/highoctane/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/super-hero-icon.png" alt="" />
<img src="https://beaverbuilder.appletreeprinting.ca/highoctane/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/super-hero-icon.png" alt="" />
  <img src="https://beaverbuilder.appletreeprinting.ca/highoctane/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/super-hero-icon.png" alt="" />
  <img src="https://beaverbuilder.appletreeprinting.ca/highoctane/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/super-hero-icon.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: resize your images properly so they fit twice in a row. that's all we can help without any code from your side

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to apply specific CSS based on device or browser dimensions.

Replace the p tag with your divs.

```css
p {
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    max-width: 65rem;
    margin: 2rem auto;
}

.grid-size {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.size1of4 {
    width: 25%;
}
.size1of4:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: green;
}
.size1of4:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .size1of4{
      width: 50%;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  .size1of4{
      width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="grid-size">
     <div class="size1of4"><p>Content</p></div>
     <div class="size1of4"><p>Content</p></div>
     <div class="size1of4"><p>Content</p></div>
     <div class="size1of4"><p>Content</p></div>
      </div>
</div>
```